# Default Parameters Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
def initialize(datum, next=nil)
@datum = datum
@next = next
end
```

**syntax error, unexpected keyword_next (SyntaxError)
  def initialize(datum, next=nil)**

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `next` as a variable, its a reserved keyword in Ruby.

[Read more here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/). It describes `next` as:

> Bumps an iterator, or a while or until block,to the next iteration,
>   unconditionally and without executing whatever may remain of the
>   block.

Comment: It's worth noting that's what "unexpected keyword keyword_X" usually means if you're stumbling over these by accident.